# No Fade on Hover for This Script

Tags: javascript, css

This script fades a div with the id "#transoverlay" after 1.5s & then fades it back in when there is mouse movement. How can I make it so that it does not fade when the mouse is hovering over #transoverlay then restarts the counter when the mouse is no longer hovering?

```
        $(function () {
            var timer;
            var fadeInBuffer = false;
            $(document).mousemove(function () {
                if (!fadeInBuffer) {
                    if (timer) {
                        console.log("clearTimer");
                        clearTimeout(timer);
                        timer = 0;
                    }

                        console.log("fadeIn");
                    $('#transoverlay').fadeIn();
                    $('html').css({
                        cursor: ''
                    });
                } else {
                    fadeInBuffer = false;
                }


                timer = setTimeout(function () {
                    console.log("fadeout");
                    $('#transoverlay').fadeOut()
                    $('html').css({
                        cursor: 'none'
                    });
                    fadeInBuffer = true;
                }, 1500)
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the hover function in jQuery: https://api.jquery.com/hover/

Comment: Yes, but I'm not really sure where to place it. I tried this but it just never fades out at all: http://jsfiddle.net/ffq2tn92/

Comment: Also tried up at the top...I'm just not sure that the if statement would be added. http://jsfiddle.net/ffq2tn92/1/